# How do I send a JSON POST from an iOS device to an ASP.NET URL

Tags: asp.net, ios, json, web-services

I am working on an app that needs to share data with a windows server. I have looked at a number of examples on the web and come up with the implementation listed below. While the iOS code and the web-service work fine independently, I don't know how to connect them together. All the examples I have seen don't show the URL of the web-service (or at least not in a manner that allows me to figure out what is going on). Please look at the value I have for ServerURL and suggest what it should be. I believe it should have the name of the entry point "doSomething" included somewhere, but I don't know what the syntax should look like. I have tried `http://texas/WebSite3/Service.asmx/doSomething` and `http://texas/WebSite3/Service.asmx?op=doSomething` but neither seems to work. Please let me know if there is any other issue present.

I assume that once I get it to work on my local system I can replace Texas with a full domain name.

Here is the iOS code:

```
-(void)checkWithServer {
// Create the POST request payload.
    NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"test@gmail.com", @"email",
                     @"John Doe", @"name",
                     nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];

    NSString *serverURL = @"http://texas/WebSite3/Service.asmx";

// Create the POST request to the server.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postdata length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postdata];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [conn start];
}
```

Here is the webservice that it talks to:

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://texas/WebSite3")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public Service () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string doSomething(string msg)
    {
        byte[] buffer = GetBytes(msg);
        XmlReader reader = System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(buffer, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
        XElement root = XElement.Load(reader);

        string result = "{\"result\":\"none\"}";

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Axeva's help this is what I came up with.

iOS code:

```
-(void)checkWithServer {
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://texas/WebSite3/Service.asmx/doSomething"];
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"test@gmail.com", @"email",
                              @"John Doe", @"name",
                              nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: postURL
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval: 60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
    [request setValue: @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                       queue: queue
                           completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if (error || !data) {
                                   // Handle the error
                               } else {
                                   // Handle the success
                               }
                           }
     ];
}
```

Web-server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://texas/WebSite3")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment   the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string doSomething(string email, string name)
    {
        return "{\"name\": \"" + name + "\", \"email\": \"" + email + "\"}";
    }
}
```

Apparently the web-server is smart enough to pull the JSON apart and assign the variables name and email.

Comment: code is working but its showing one deprecated error:( CompletionHandler is deprecated use NsUrlSession ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any magic with the .NET causing the issues.  Just try something like this:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://texas/WebSite3/Service.asmx/doSomething"];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 @"test@gmail.com", @"email",
                 @"John Doe", @"name",
                 nil];

NSString *postValues = [jsonDict urlEncodedString];
NSData *jsonData = [postValues dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: postURL
                                                       cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval: 60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
// [request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-type"];
[request setValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                   queue: queue
                       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (error || !data) {
                               // Handle the error
                           } else {
                               // Handle the success
                           }
                       }
 ];
```

Comment: Axeva, huge step forward but I am not there yet. I get this message back. "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027msg\u0027". The message is JSON formatted so I know I am 98% there. How do I tell it that the incoming value is intended for msg. Or should I have something different in doSomething?

Comment: It's been a while since I did .NET, but I think your web service is returning JSON, but requires form key value pairs for the input.  Try the change I made to the source above.  You'll see where I commented out the line that configures the send format as JSON and where I add the line to send form encoded data.  See if that helps.

Comment: It looks like the `content-type` should be `application/json`.

Comment: Okay.  That's what I had originally.

Comment: Any idea why the response I get back in iOS is:
`{"d": "{\"name\": \"John Doe\", \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\"}"}` Where did the "d" come from?

Comment: Sorry, now you're more in to the ASP.NET realm.  I'd suggest asking a new question and provide the full source of your web service.

Comment: ASP.NET will automatically serialize your web method's response into an object called "d". Unfortunately, there's no way around it. On a good note, it looks like you're response is coming back correctly!